# Why I cannot create queue in rabbitmq in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm new to RabbitMQ.

I installed RabbitMQ server on Windows 10. I can login to the server in web browser. When I run the client code below (uses AMQP-CPP library), neigther `channel.onSuccess` nor `channel.onError` are called. And, I don't see my declared `my-queue` queue and `my-exchange` exchange in the web browser.

If I understood correctly, I need to add some event loop (?). But, I cannot find any example for Windows. Can you explain what can be the issue?

```
int main()
{
    // create an instance of your own tcp handler
    MyTcpHandler myHandler;

    // address of the server
    //AMQP::Address address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/");
    AMQP::Address address("localhost", 15672, AMQP::Login("guest", "guest"), "");

    // create a AMQP connection object
    AMQP::TcpConnection connection(&myHandler, address);

    // and create a channel b
    AMQP::TcpChannel channel(&connection);

    // use the channel object to call the AMQP method you like
    channel.declareExchange("my-exchange", AMQP::fanout)
        .onSuccess([]()
    {
        std::cout << "declared exchange " << std::endl;
    }).onError([](const char *message)
    {
        std::cout << "error: " << message << std::endl;

    });

    channel.declareQueue("my-queue");
    channel.bindQueue("my-exchange", "my-queue", "my-routing-key");

    std::cout << "Press Enter..." << std::endl;
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

**MyTcpHandler**

```
class MyTcpHandler : public AMQP::TcpHandler
{
public:

    virtual void onConnected(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) {}
    virtual void onError(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, const char *message) {}
    virtual void onClosed(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) {}
    virtual void monitor(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, AMQP::tcp::Socket fd, int flags) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

came across same issue myself today.
The problem is you have to implement your own hanlder, or nothing will be sent.

The bundled TcpHandler is based on boost asio tcpHandler which is posix only, and will not compile on windows. see [this link](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/200#issuecomment-372605898)

Too shame it's doesn't have internal built-in handler, this is so "basic"...

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting on the wrong port 15672 is the management plugin port  , you need to connect on Port 5672 which is the AMQP port

Please correct the code as under

```
AMQP::Address address("localhost", 5672, AMQP::Login("guest", "guest"), "");
```

Comment: When you connect do you see a new connection under connections tab in the management console web browser ?

Comment: No, I don't. That's why I assumed I need event loop for it to work/connect.

Comment: Did you try this sample https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/blob/master/examples/libev.cpp , if not can you try and make sure that your setup is correct

Comment: I just tried the example with `LibBoostAsioHandler` and it didn't work.

Comment: @theateist , i think there is then probably an issue with the setup...since the example does work well..

Comment: The example has `#include "amqpcpp/linux_tcp.h"` in `libboostasio.h` which is not working on WIndows. If I comment `#include "amqpcpp/linux_tcp.h"` I get a lot of compiler errors. Do I need to fix the errors or there is equivalent windows version for `#include "amqpcpp/linux_tcp.h"`?

Comment: Even if I comment out `Watcher`, `Timer` and body of `monitor` function that are not necessary in `LibBoostAsioHandler` class so I could build the example it still doesn't work. I don't see any connection or queue in management console web browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199528/discussion-between-soumen-mukherjee-and-theateist).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use HareDu 2 Broker API to do it using the below code. Docs can be found here: https://github.com/ahives/HareDu2

```
var result = _container.Resolve<IBrokerObjectFactory>()
                .Object<Queue>()
                .Create(x =>
                {
                    x.Queue("your_queue");
                    x.Configure(c =>
                    {
                        c.IsDurable();
                        c.AutoDeleteWhenNotInUse();
                        c.HasArguments(arg =>
                        {
                            arg.SetQueueExpiration(1000);
                            arg.SetPerQueuedMessageExpiration(2000);
                        });
                    });
                    x.Targeting(t =>
                    {
                        t.VirtualHost("your_vhost");
                        t.Node("your_node");
                    });
                });
```